# Stacked Washing Machine - Aggrigator/Motor Belt Keeps Coming Off

Tags: washing-machine

I have a GE Stackable Washer/Dryer(washer is top loader) and the belt for the aggregator/Motor that drives the Spin Cycle keeps coming off. It appears to be at random, and while is not a big deal, I am wondering if I just need a tighter belt from wear and tear or if it’s something more.

Comment: There is  belt tension adjustment

Comment: Also check on the belt alignment.  The pulleys need to be in line, if out of line by a small amount they will jump off also.